# Why am I unable to open Laravel using this Docker configuration?

Tags: php, laravel, docker

This is my backend service (`docker-compose.yml`).

```
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: ../Dockerfile.laravel
    command: php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code
```

The content of `Dockerfile.laravel` is:

```
FROM php:8.0.3-alpine3.13

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    sync && \
    install-php-extensions @composer bcmath

WORKDIR /code
```

I'm starting everything with `docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate --remove-orphans`.

On which port should I access this Laravel app? http://localhost:8000/ says the site cannot be reached, port `80` same effect. What am I missing?

BTW. When I `cd backend` I can do `php artisan` and Laravel displays all artisan commands. I can list routes with no issues.

Comment: There is no port exposed...

Comment: Maybe add an `EXPOSE <port>` in the `Dockerfile.laravel`

Comment: I've added EXPOSE 8080 after WORKDIR /code, then did `docker-compose up -d --build --force-recreate --remove-orphans` and same effect. http://localhost:8080/ -> This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.

Comment: Maybe you need pdo? RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

Comment: You'll need to expose the portmapping from the docker-compose.yml. And `localhost` is somewhat special, because localhost always refers to the docker container itself. Your computer does not forward localhost to the docker... Add a new entry in your `hosts` file and give it a nice URL. Don't forget to add the server name in the webserver configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a port on your container in your `docker-compose` file. For example, if you want to expose port 8080 in your container to port 8080 locally, you'll add it like this.

```
backend:
  build:
    context: ./backend
    dockerfile: ../Dockerfile.laravel
  command: php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0
  volumes:
    - ./backend:/code
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
```